# How can I save data when offline in my Android app?

Tags: java, android, offline

I'm creating an app for Android in Java. I can send info to a webservice but when i'm offline i want to store the info and when the phone gets connected to the internet i want to send it to the webservice. 
Can anyone help me? 
Thanks

Comment: Store the data you want to send in your sqlite db and check every time if any data exist, in this case call again the ws and delete those rows from the Database if the response is ok otherwise don't delete them in order to retry again when the connection is avail available. That's all!

Answer (score 3):

1. Store your data in SQLite data-base. You can read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).
2. Check in BroadcastReceiver if connectivity changed and update online DB and delete the content from Sqlite DB.

   ```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       String s = intent.getAction();
       if (s.equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {
           if (IsNetworkAvailable(context)) {
               // update your online data-base and delete all rows from SQlite
           }
       return;
      }
   }
   ```

Method isNetworkAvailable:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context mContext) {
    Context context = mContext.getApplicationContext();
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                    return true;
                }
             }
        }
    }
   return false;
}
```

You also need permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Thankkss for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Offline storage and sync seem simple at first sight but you need to be careful and consider the following:

First get familiar with the [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) available in the platform and chose the most convenient for your app scenario.

Second, design your sync mechanism in an [efficient way](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html) so your app won't drain the battery life.

[This](https://github.com/yigit/dev-summit-architecture-demo) is a good resource to check the entire structure of an android app that cares about working offline and properly sync with the server as network becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

Save your info to a `SQLite` database and use a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen when network connection is available. When connection is available, start a `Service` that sends the saved data to your webservice.

Answer (score 1):

In the event, where you upload your data, check if Internet connection is available or not, if not, store the data as textfile or object and name it like needToUpload1, 2, 3.

Then, whenever the device is online, check if the there is any file named like that. If so, upload it via service and delete the file.

That's just my opinion how i'll do it but really depends on data.
You can find how to do every step on this site so i hope it will help.